# How to get empty ol inside li when li is in sub-level of list item in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code snippet, I tried to get and highlight every `li` that contain empty `ol` element (`ol` without any `li` element) regardless of number of sub-level.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var Text = '';
  var emptyLiText = '';
  $('ol#myUL > li').each(function() {
    lenOl = $(this).find('ol').length;

    if (lenOl > 0) {
      lenOlLi = $(this).find('ol').children('li').length;

      if (lenOlLi == 0) {

        $(this).addClass('error_item');
        emptyLiText = $(this).clone() //clone the element
          .children() //select all the children
          .remove() //remove all the children
          .end() //again go back to selected element
          .text();

        emptyLiText = $.trim(emptyLiText);
        Text += ' ' + emptyLiText;

        $('.message').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">' +
          '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button><b>Unable to Save:</b> Menu item <b>' + Text + '</b> is parent item but does not has sub-item inside.</div>');

        breakout = true;
        // return false;

      } else {
        ($(this).hasClass('error_item') == true) ? $(this).removeClass('error_item'): '';
      }


    }
  })
})
```

```css
.error_item {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="message"></div>
<ol id="myUL">
  <li>Sample Item 1
    <ol>
      <li>Sample Item 2
        <ol></ol>
      </li>
      <li>Account</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Sample Item 3
    <ol></ol>
  </li>
  <li>Sample Item 4</li>
  <li>Sample Item 5
    <ol>
      <li>Sample Item 6
        <ol>
          <li>Sample Item 7
            <ol></ol>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

However, currently my trying could only get first level of `li` that has empty `ol` inside. When empty `ol` is in second or third level of list, it get ignore, ex. Sample Item 2 and Sample Item 7.

My question is how can I get empty `ol` inside `li` regardless of how many sub-level it is? Because my project is related to this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `$('ol#myUL > li')` selector where `>` means immediate child.

Replace `>` with a space to get list of all `<li>` elements inside parent `<ol>`

something like this
`$('ol#myUL li')`

Comment: ah! it is, it took hours fixing this. Thanks very much for your help ;)

Answer (score 1):

> ...get and highlight every li that contain empty ol element

Plain vanilla JS

```
const emptyOl = [].prototype.filter.call(document.querySelectorAll('ol'), el => el.childNodes.length < 1)
const liOfEmptyOl = [].prototype.filter.call(emptyOl, el => el.parentNode.tagName == 'LI')
const highLighted = [].prototype.map.call(liOfEmptyOl, el => el.classList.add('highlighted'))

if (liOfEmptyOl.length > 0) console.error('Danger')
```

CSS

```
.highlighted {border: 1px solid red}
```